# Can you stagger animation in, but unstaggered on out, in AnimXYZ?

Tags: css, animation

I have [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/cassidoo/pen/PoaqyPG/2e30cf3586f20a658fc8e0b0a33c5926) here where I'm using [AnimXYZ](https://animxyz.com/). I'm trying to figure out if I can stagger in the animation, but make all of the elements go out at the same time. I haven't been able to find any docs or anything on it.

Relevant code for what I have so far:

```
// HTML

<div class="diagram" xyz="duration-6 ease-in stagger-5 narrow-75% fade-100% origin-left left-2">
    <div class="rectangle xyz-in">
      <div class="text">whatever the text is, this is a sample</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle xyz-in">
      <div class="text">whatever the text is, this is a sample</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
// JS

const rs = document.querySelectorAll(".rectangle");

setInterval(() => {
  rs.forEach((r) => {
    r.classList.toggle("xyz-in");
    r.classList.toggle("xyz-out");
  });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by breaking up the interval into parts instead of toggling everything at once:

```js
const rs = document.querySelectorAll(".rectangle");
let count = 1;

setInterval(() => {
  if (count <= 5) {
    count += 1;
  } else if (count === 6) {
    count += 1;
    flip();
  } else {
    count = 0;
    flip();
  }
}, 1000);

function flip() {
  rs.forEach((r) => {
    r.classList.toggle("xyz-in");
    r.classList.toggle("xyz-out");
  });
}
```